# Javascript not functioning in firefox

Tags: javascript

Here's the current code

```
if (obj&&obj.tagName.toLowerCase()=="input") {
  obj.filter=regex;
  on(obj,"keypress",function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode<32) return true;
    if (!(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(this.filter))) {
       e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false;
     }
  }
}
```

It seems to function just fine on Google Chrome but does not seem to work on Firefox. **I have no real idea about tailoring javascript to the browser**

Anyways I'm sure this is a 2 minute solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't work in Firefox. Can you post a working example on for example jsbin?

Comment: It would probably take 2 minutes, but only in case you posted relevant html code and complete `keyup` event function. Therefor I forecast it would take 15 to 20 minutes.

Comment: I think after dedicating about 2 minutes I could find the problem. The quasi-duplicate question should answer the question.